# What version of java does gradle use to run your application?

Tags: gradle

I have a JavaFX project I am working on using Gradle. What version of java is used when I use the gradle `run` task from the application plugin?

In IntelliJ I can go into the Gradle settings and change the "Gradle JVM" to any version I want. Is this just the version of java that is used to run the build? Or is this also the version that my application will be run on?

Where does my JAVA_HOME come into this, if at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irrespective of IDEs, Gradle will use whatever language level of the JVM that is running Gradle. Typically whatever the value is for `JAVA_HOME`.

See [Environment variables](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables) and [Targeting a specific Java version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_cross_compilation)

The new way to do it as of Gradle 6.7 is to use [Toolchains for JVM projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html)

Your IDE should respect whatever Gradle configuration that is configured.